# MySQL: Prepare statement failed

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

I have class with function, which prepares SQL statement to put data into database, but there's an error I can not figure it out, why is happening?

```
public function vnos_narocila($user) //, $hvrsta_narocila, $hlastna_nabava, $hos, $hsm_dn, $hoe, $hartikel1, $hkolicina_artikel1, $hem1, $hartikel2, $hkolicina_artikel2, $hem2, $hartikel3, $hkolicina_artikel3, $hem3, $hartikel4, $hkolicina_artikel4, $hem4, $hartikel5, $hkolicina_artikel5, $hem5, $hartikel6, $hkolicina_artikel6, $hem6, $hartikel7, $hkolicina_artikel7, $hem7, $hartikel8, $hkolicina_artikel8, $hem8, $hartikel9, $hkolicina_artikel9, $hem9, $hartikel10, $hkolicina_artikel10, $hem10, $hprevzemnik, $hopomba, $hzeljen_datum)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM nabava ORDER BY id_nabava DESC LIMIT 1"; //pridobitev zaporedne številke v letu
        if( !$this->stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($sql) )
            throw new Exception("MySQL Prepare statement failed: ".$this->mysqli->error);

        $this->stmt->execute();
        $zadnji_zapis = $this->stmt->get_result();
        $zadnji_zapis = $zadnji_zapis-> fetch_array();

        $leto = date('Y');
        if ( !$zadnji_zapis or $zadnji_zapis[leto] != $leto)
            $zap_st=1; 
        else
            $zap_st = $zadnji_zapis[zap_st]+1; 

        $narocilo = "N-".$zap_st."-".$hoe."/".$leto;  //kreiranje številke naročila

        $sql_vnos = "INSERT INTO nabava (vrsta_narocila, lastna_dobava, os, sm_dn, prevzemnik, opomba, zeljen_datum_dobave, narocilo, uporabnik, datum_vnosa, zap_st, oe, leto) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW(), ?, ?, ? )";
        if( !$this->stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($sql_vnos) )
            throw new Exception("MySQL Prepare statement failed: ".$this->mysqli->error);

        $this->stmt->bind_param("iiisssisiiii", $hvrsta_narocila, $hlastna_dobava, $hos, $hsm_dn, $hprevzemnik, $hopomba, $hzeljen_datum, $narocilo, $user, $zap_st, $hoe, $leto );
        if( $this->stmt->execute() )
            return $this->stmt->insert_id;

        return $narocilo;
    }
```

Here is the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: MySQL Prepare statement failed: in
>   /var/www/html/intra_komunalaBrezice/skripte/nabava.php:111 Stack
>   trace: #0 /var/www/html/intra_komunalaBrezice/nabava_vnos.php(27):
>   nabava->vnos_narocila(1, '1', '1', '1', '200401', '1005', '1', '1',
>   '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
>   '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'test', 'test',
>   '2018-07-04') #1 {main} thrown in
>   /var/www/html/intra_komunalaBrezice/skripte/nabava.php on line 111

Please help...

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Show us `ERROR`

Comment: Count your placeholders.

Comment: `INSERT` query you pass `14 column` and its values `13`

Comment: Thnx, i don't know how I missed it... now there's a problem with saving values into database. SQL statement is prepared fine, but values aren't stored into database. There is no error, just nothing comes to database.

Answer (score 0):

There was a mistake in number of columns and number of values passed.

I'm sorry, I should see that.